# IE8 doesn't show anything in div after jQuery append operation, even though the div has content (technically)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm having a problem with IE, I can't seem to get the div to display contents in IE8 even though when I ask for the contents of the div back again, it appears to be populated. Works fine on Chrome, Safari, Firefox. Just not in IE.

http://jsfiddle.net/Vb6nK/

The dev site is here (so you can see what it would look like if the images were available): http://www.antarctic-design.co.uk/oboe/

Many thanks,

Eamonn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is - bizarrely - your CSS.

Take out this line in the CSS

```
.information_block {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fafafa',endColorstr='#eaeaea')";
}
```

The jsfiddle works for me when I remove that line

**EDIT** you can just remove the `-ms-` prefix, it's not needed for the filter to work in IE8

Comment: Awesome. My only issue now is that it doesn't calculate the height properly for the new content, so it overlaps with the footer.

Comment: glad that helped. Not sure about the height issue (can't see you setting it anywhere). You could try adding `overflow:hidden` to `.information_block` since the float is escaping. Otherwise I'd raise a new question.

Comment: So, now in this page, http://www.antarctic-design.co.uk/oboe/ when the content is loaded, IE doesn't recalculate the size. Do you know how to force it to do so?

Comment: Ah, only seeing your last comment there now.